# Elasticsearch aggregate counts based on a filter

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, faceted-search

I've worked on several facet and filter based searches in the past with Solr but I'm struggling to achieve parity with Elasticsearch.

I understand that aggregations are calculated against the results of a query or globally if no query is specified. This is fine, however I would like the *counts* of those aggregations to be based on the results of a filter.

In Solr this is straightforward - just specify a query and filter - but with Elasticsearch a filter has no effect on aggregates and the documentation is very confusing.

My desired output for the following query is for the `suggestions` bucket to be scoped to the query but the resulting counts therein to be scoped to the specified `filter`:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "range": {
            "published": {
                "gte": "now-1y",
                "lt": "now"
            }
        }
    },
    "filter": {
        {
            "term": {
                "tag.id": "123"
            }
        },
        {
            "term": {
                "tag.id": "456"
            }
        },
    },
    "aggs": {
        "tags": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "tag"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "suggestions": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "name",
                        "size": 10,
                        "min_doc_count": 1
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "id": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "id",
                                "size": 1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And given the example mapping:

```
{
    "mappings":{
        "content":{
            "properties":{
                "id":{
                    "type":"string",
                    "index":"not_analyzed"
                },
                "title":{
                    "type":"string"
                },
                "byline":{
                    "type":"string",
                    "index":"not_analyzed"
                },
                "body":{
                    "type":"string"
                },
                "publishedDate":{
                    "type":"date",
                    "format":"dateOptionalTime"
                },
                "tag":{
                    "type":"nested",
                    "include_in_parent":true,
                    "properties":{
                        "id":{
                            "type":"integer"
                        },
                        "name":{
                            "type":"string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to use a [filtered aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html)?

Comment: I have yes, but I wasn't able to get the results I'd expected. I'll investigate further.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do. Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the expected results by :

1. keeping the query where it is,
2. but moving the `filter` part (what you have is equivalent to a `post_filter` actually and is only applied on the results after aggregations have run) into a `filter` aggregation

Basically this should work:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "published": {
        "gte": "now-1y",
        "lt": "now"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "tags": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "tag"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "suggestions": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "tag.name",
            "size": 10,
            "min_doc_count": 1
          },
          "aggs": {
            "filtered": {
              "filter": {
                "terms": {
                  "tag.id": [
                    "123",
                    "456"
                  ]
                }
              },
              "aggs": {
                "id": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "tag.id",
                    "size": 1
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry... I was a little premature! Unfortunately this request will result in all counts being 0. Should the nesting be reversed for the filter aggregation?

Comment: Can you share a sample document + your mapping so I can reproduce the issue?

Comment: Sample mapping added =]

Comment: Can you also share a sample document and what counts you expect for it. With the document I'm using I do get counts.

Comment: Did you see my above comment?